# Can we reuse the same API developed for Mobile application. Does it affect performance of mobile app anyway

Tags: rest, api, web-services

We have a Rest API services for web application. Now we need to build for andriod mobile application. The json response will be of huge data but only very few data is required for mobile application. Does reusing of API with huge response will affect performance? Do I have to customize the API for mobile app ? Can I have the source code of mobile and web bundled together since some common functionality can be reused?

Comment: You're phrasing your question as multiple different questions here, even though it's effectively one question. I'd edit your question to make it clearer - your goal is to reuse source code and API across both a web application and a mobile one, and you'd like to know the tradeoffs. It may help to separate the subquestions into their distinct bullet points with further detail.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned that only a part of the current api's response is necessary is required for mobile it is better to have a seperate api service for web and mobile.
It is totally unnecessary to send data that is not required to the client and is not a good practice.
I suggest maintaining seperate api services for web and mobile unless the response is same.